# List becomes empty when the control reaches to build in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
void main() => runApp( MaterialApp(
      home:  HomePage(),
    ));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() =>  _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        Map<String, dynamic> _userDetails =
            user.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value?.toString()));

        _userDetails.addAll(_userDetails);

        print("fdsfsd: ");
        print(_userDetails.length);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }
```

Till this point things do work fine. The print statement shows the good length of the list.

When this needs to go in the GUI through build, there suddenly the list becomes empty:

This print statement results 0. I have removed the extra code for clarity sake.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("FFFF: ");
    print(_userDetails.length);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
      ..........
  }
```

Rest of the code is here:

```
List<UserDetails> _searchResult = [];
List<UserDetails> _userDetails = [];

final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

class UserDetails {
  final int? id;
  final String? firstName, lastName, profileUrl;

  UserDetails(
      {this.id,
      this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.profileUrl =
          'https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/3NbrfEiECotKyhcUhgPJHbrL7zM=/950x534/filters:quality(90)/2014%2F06%2F02%2Fc0%2Fzuckheadsho.a33d0.jpg'});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserDetails(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName: json['name'],
      lastName: json['username'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing

```
_userDetails.addAll(_userDetails);
```

this will add `_userDetails` to itself.

It might help to write it as

```
this._userDetails.addAll(_userDetails);
```

so it gets added to the right one. But personally I would suggest to use 2 different names. Like leave the underscore at the local one, like

```
    Map<String, dynamic> userDetails =
        user.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value?.toString()));

    _userDetails.addAll(userDetails);
```

EDIT:

I realize that this also won't work because you actually want UserDetail objects in there, so I think this is what you want:

```
  for (Map user in responseJson) {
    _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user);
  }
```

EDIT2:

Since `user` is of type `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>`, this:

```
factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
```

needs to be changed to

```
factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)
```

as well

Comment: I tried `_userDetails.add( UserDetails.fromJson( user ));`. This gives the error: `Map<dynamic, dynamic> cannot be assigned to Map<String, dynamic>`. Please note I have replaced `addAll` with `add`.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl just changing `factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` to  `factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)` might be enough to solve that

Comment: This solved the problem. Please put it in your answer. Thank you for your effort.